# Problemas al filtrar con un formulario reactivo en Angular

Tags: angular, observable, reactiveformsmodule

En esta aplicacion: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/avales/formulario-avales/formulario-avales.component.ts

Si accedes al menu Avales>ver/Editar accedes a un listado de Avales que intento filtrar usando un formulario

[image: formulario]

En el componente que se abre en esa ruta "filtro-avales.component" monto lo siguiente

[image: componente]

Es decir, tengo un formulario con los elementos que usaré para filtrar el dataSource que mando al componente que muestra el listado en si

Al configurar el formulario

```
 private inicializarFormulario(){
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group(this.formularioOriginal);

  this.form.valueChanges
   .subscribe(
     valores => {
       this.dataSource = this.dataSourceOriginal;
       this.buscar(valores);
    }
   );
  }
```

En la funcion Buscar hago lo siguiente

```
 private buscar(valores: any) {
 ....
  valores.tipoAval==0
  ? this.dataSource=this.dataSourceOriginal
  : this.dataSource=this.dataSource.filter(a=>a.tipoAvalId==valores.tipoAval)
  ....
 }
```

Si depuro veo que pasa por aqui y que el método filter funciona

[image: filter]

Pero luego no veo el listado filtrado

Y lo curioso del tema es que ha habido ejecuciones en las que si ha funcionado y otras en las que no. No se si tiene algo que ver con el asincronismo de los observables.

Esto mismo lo hago en Ofertas y aqui me funciona siempre

[image: ofertas]

Alguna idea, por favor?

Salu2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en la función `buscar` de `filtro-avales.component.ts`. En este trozo de código:

```
    valores.tipoAval==0
      ? this.dataSource=this.dataSourceOriginal
      : this.dataSource=this.dataSource.filter(a=>a.tipoAvalId==valores.tipoAval)

    valores.estadoAval==0
    ? this.dataSource=this.dataSourceOriginal
    : this.dataSource=this.dataSource.filter(a=>a.estadoAvalId==valores.estadoAval)

    valores.avalista==0
    ? this.dataSource=this.dataSourceOriginal
    : this.dataSource=this.dataSource.filter(a=>a.avalistaId==valores.avalista)

    valores.responsable==0
    ? this.dataSource=this.dataSourceOriginal
    : this.dataSource=this.dataSource.filter(a=>a.responsableId==valores.responsable)

    valores.cliente==0
    ? this.dataSource=this.dataSourceOriginal
    : this.dataSource=this.dataSource.filter(a=>a.clienteId==valores.cliente)
```

Si te fijas si `tipoAval` tiene valor realiza el filtrado, pero como el siguiente (`estadoAval`) está sin valor pone en la variable `this.dataSource` de nuevo todos los valores (`this.dataSource=this.dataSourceOriginal`).

Habría que hacer algo más de pruebas para comprobar que no "rompe" nada diferente, pero creo que con cambiar todos esos  `this.dataSource=this.dataSourceOriginal` por `this.dataSource=this.dataSource` te funcionará.

A ver si hay suerte

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo estas usando Angular Material. La tabla tiene sus defectos, y uno de los peores es el filtrado de la información. A pesar que puedes aplicar un `filter` a `dataSource`, deberías aplicarlo en si a `dataSource.data` puesto que es el método que contiene la información, sin embargo puede no funcionar. Debido a ello se creo [filterPredicate()](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) y lo filtrarías así mas o menos

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate(a => a.tipoAvalId === valores.tipoAval );
```

Si te das cuenta eso no crea un arreglo como `filter()`, si no que internamente la clase filtra los datos, sin perder los otros. Al ser una solo instancia el `filterPredicate` en la función que pasa como parámetro podrías meter toda tu lógica para que filtre no solo en uno, si no en varios campos.